# System.PlatformNotSupportedException

Tags: xamarin, release, xamarin.uwp

Xamarin.UWP Release Embedded Image error,but debug no problem.
Code short and very easy.

MainPage.xaml code below

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="EmbImg.MainPage"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EmbImg">
    
        <StackLayout>
            <Image Source="{local:EmbeddedImg ResourceId=EmbImg.Picture.pic.ico}"
             VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage>
```

EmbeddedImg.cs code below

```
    internal class EmbeddedImg : IMarkupExtension
    { 
      public string ResourceId { get; set; }
      public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
      {
         return ImageSource.FromResource(ResourceId);
      }
    }
```

error message:
System.PlatformNotSupportedException
Message=Operation is not supported on this platform.

Sir: give me any idea to slove this error.

Comment: Use an image editor to convert your icon into a .png file. Use that .png file instead.

Comment: Change *.png picture got same error message !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
return ImageSource.FromResource(ResourceId);
```

fix code

```
return ImageSource.FromResource(ResourceId,typeof(EmbeddedImg).assembly);
```